# How do I change to another accent

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to make the dot on the lowercase I slanted but leave the rest of the I normal like as if i was typing in a different accent for the word Taino (Native American people)

I looked for an option on the tool bar and found an equation button but wouldn't allow me to change the accent so I looked again and I couldn't find a special characteristic box to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure TinyMCE to load the Character Map plugin, which makes it easier to insert special characters like this (and others) into editor content:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/charmap/

Add the `charmap` plugin to your `tinymce.init()` configuration object:

```
plugins: "charmap",
```

You can then add the Character Map button to the toolbar:

```
  toolbar: 'charmap',
```

Here is a Tiny Fiddle example: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/iqiaab

If TinyMCE is *not* configured to use this plugin, end-users can also add characters like this into the source code of editor text via HTML Entities:

[https://lilith.fisica.ufmg.br/~wag/TRANSF/codehtml.html](https://lilith.fisica.ufmg.br/%7Ewag/TRANSF/codehtml.html)

...or in the editor body via key combinations described here:

https://howtotypeanything.com/i-with-accent/